# How to include local script file on React page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, barbajs

I'm implementing [`barba JS`](https://barba.js.org/) on my `React` website but can't seem to get the file to work on the page. For reference, my folder structure is as follows:

```
theme
  pages
    Homepage.js
    Contact.js
  utils
    anim.js
    helpers.js
  index.js
```

On my `index.js` file, I'm trying to `import` my `anim.js` script so that the file is applied to all my `pages`. However, upon compilation, I'm getting a `'delay' is not defined  no-undef` error on `anim.js`, even though `delay` is defined (because I'm importing `gsap`).

**Homepage.js** (`Contact.js` is similar, only difference being the `data-barba-namespace`)

```
import React from "react";
import LoadingScreen from "../components/LoadingScreen/LoadingScreen";
import Hero from "../components/Hero/Hero";

class Homepage extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <>
        <LoadingScreen />
        <div data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
          <Hero />
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

**anim.js**

```
import { pageTransition, contentAnimation } from "./helpers";
import barba from '@barba/core';
import gsap from "gsap";

barba.init({
  sync: true,
  transitions: [{
    async leave(data){
      const done = this.async();
      pageTransition();
      await delay(1000);
      done();
    }, async enter(data){
      contentAnimation();
    }, async leave(data){
      contentAnimation();
    }}
  ]
});
```

**helpers.js**

```
export function pageTransition(){
  var timeline = gsap.timeline();
  timeline.to("loadingScreen",{
    duration: 1.2,
    width: "100%",
    left: "0",
    ease: "Expo.easeInOut"
  });
  timeline.to("loadingScreen",{
    duration: 1,
    width: "100%",
    left: "100%",
    ease: "Expo.easeInOut",
    delay: 0.3
  });
  timeline.set(".LoadingScreen", { left: "-100%" } );
}

export function contentAnimation(){
  var timeline = gsap.timeline();
  timeline.from("animate-this", {
    duration: 1,
    y: 30,
    opacity: 0,
    stagger: 0.4,
    delay: 0.2
  });
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { pageTransition, contentAnimation } from "./utils/helpers";
import { barba } from '../node_modules/@barba/core';

import anim from "./utils/anim";
import "./scss/style.scss";

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

**index.html** (shows `barba` wrapper)

```
<body data-barba="wrapper">
  <main id="root"></main>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you require to use the file as an external script? Barba seem to offer an easy to use [npm module](https://barba.js.org/docs/getstarted/install/#Use-with-a-bundler) as well!

Comment: Hi @EmileBergeron - I have the `barba` package installed via `npm` already. My `barba.js` file is just a file with my custom `barba` related transitions and that's what I'm trying to add to my pages.

Comment: I don't see anything importing or defining the name `barba` in barba.js, but you're trying to call an `init()` method of it. Is that being defined globally by another script on the page? If not, there should be an error somewhere like "cannot access property 'init' of undefined".

Comment: @solarshado - You are correct, I haven't `imported` barba into my `barba.js` file. I have done so now and updated my above question to showcase the code. To your second point,  "should be an error somewhere", this is the thing, even though I have `barba.js` in `Homepage.js` and `Contact.js`, I don't see any errors or any kind. Now that I've done the import, still the same results. No errors and no transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually put the below code inside useEffect to create and load script in your index.js or which ever file you wish

```
useEffect(() => {

const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "localfilepath";
script.async = true;
script.defer = true;
document.body.append(script);

 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence of imports looks wrong. All node_modules should be imported first before local files like `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { barba } from '../node_modules/@barba/core';


import { pageTransition, contentAnimation } from "./utils/helpers";
import anim from "./utils/anim";

import App from "./App";
import "./scss/style.scss";
```

Or you can lazy import module and initiate app on load success.

```js
(async () => {
  // Dynamically imported module (runtime)
  await import('../node_modules/@barba/core');
  const root = document.getElementById("root");
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
})();
```

**Read More:** https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/react-lazy-dynamic-imports/